# Dynamically changing row height after font size of entire NSTableView / NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'm dynamically changing the font size of all the cells in an NSOutlineView. I'm able to successfully change the actual font size:  (font size exaggerated for effect):

```
id cell = [myOutlineColumn dataCell];
[cell setFont: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Geneva" size:32.0] ];
```

But the row height of the rows in the NSOutlineView don't change.  The cells all have the previous height (17 pt) -- but with 32pt text. I've tried [myTable tile] and [myTable reloadData] but that doesn't recompute the row heights.

I saw -noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged.  Is loading up an NSIndexSet and calling noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged the only method of getting the rows automatically adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call -setRowHeight: on the outline view after changing the font size. E.g. [outlineView setRowHeight:[font pointSize]+2.0].

For getting the best height for the row, here's what I do in my app:

```
CGFloat KBDefaultLineHeightForFont (NSFont *font, BOOL sizeForTextField)
{
    if (font == nil)
        font = [NSFont userFontOfSize:0];   // Use default system font if font is nil.

    NSLayoutManager *lm = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];

    if (sizeForTextField)
        [lm setTypesetterBehavior:NSTypesetterBehavior_10_2_WithCompatibility];

    // On Mountain Lion and above, string drawing is done without using screen fonts, so we must do the same.
    if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) > NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7)
        [lm setUsesScreenFonts:NO];

    CGFloat height = [lm defaultLineHeightForFont:font];
    [lm release];

    return height;
}
```

Then:

```
CGFloat rowHeight = MAX(16.0, KBDefaultLineHeightForFont(ovFont, YES) + 3.0);
[outlineView setRowHeight:rowHeight];
[[[[outlineView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:0] dataCell] setFont:ovFont];
```

Comment: So there's no way for the take itself to ask the cells for their heights, and build row height from that?

Comment: Not directly, because the cell heights don't change until you set the row height of the outline view. What you could probably do is call -cellSizeForBounds: on the cell, passing FLT_MAX for the rect height. I do that in an outline view that has variable row heights for cells that can wrap text, but it's probably overkill if all your rows are going to be the same height. The way I do it for a case similar to yours is to call a custom function to get the best height for the font using NSLayoutManager's -defaultLineHeightForFont:, then add a couple of pixels and set that using -setRowHeight.

Comment: I've updated my answer above with the code I use to calculate the best row height for the font used.

Comment: this was a fantastic answer.  Very clear.  But isn't an NSFont "deprecated"?  Shouldn't we be using CTFont?  And if so, how do we get the toll-free bridged CTFontRef (which is const) to an NSFont* param, such as setFont?